# android intent gets redelivered when launching with home button

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

Here is what i am having an issue with:

i am starting an activity by pressing the notification bar which contains an extra to mark that the activity is started from notifications. i use this flag in the oncreate method of my activity (Which is the main screen of my app) to launch a new screen on top of that one if the extra from notifications is set.

so that part works great. now what happens is when i click the notifications and i exit the app by pressing the back key, if i afterwards restart it from the recent's by pressing the home button it seems to redeliver that last intent that came from the notifications so it starts my screen again. i have tried a bunch of flags in the manifest and i haven't been successful so far.

here are the flags i am using for the activity.

```
 android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" 
    android:alwaysRetainTaskState="false"
```

any ideas here?
thank you.

Comment: i am using a TabActivity for the main screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so it turns out that if your activity is declared singleTop then the last intent is getting redelivered every time you start the activity by pressing the home button.

as a workaround i tried using the onConfiguration changed to save a flag when the intent was used but it didn't work because the activity was actually destroyed and it wasn't just changing orientation. finally what i did was save that flag in shared preferences and set it to false every time i send a new intent towards the singleTop activity and setting it to true every time the intent extras are consumed.

so problem dirty fixed, but i am curious of how behavior like this is normal :(.

Comment: You can check if the intent is *NOT* from **history** with `if((intent.getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY) == 0)`.

Comment: neevek you should add this as an answer, fixed my issue.